# EF5 Entry not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, updates, updatemodel

Im trying to update an entry with EF5 with the following actionresult:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Reference reference = db.References.Single(x => x.Id == id);
            db.Entry(reference).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            //Other stuff regarding files/images

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
     }
```

Nothing happens. When I debug it, it goes trough the code as everything was fine. But nothing is updated in the db.

Here's the model if needed:

```
public class Reference
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Headline { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> ImageUploadMain { get; set; } 
        public String MainFileName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> ImageUpload { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Image> Files { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RefProperties> Properties { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public virtual Reference Reference { get; set; }
}

public class RefProperties
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reference> References { get; set; }
}
```

Not only is the related entries not updated, a main property like "Headline" cant be updated either. What am I doing wrong? Create/delete works fine btw.

Comment: You seem not to update anything before `SaveChanges()`, is that right?

Comment: @GertArnold Thats right. db.Entry(reference).State = EntityState.Modified; is the only thing before SaveChanges()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what I was looking for:

```
TryUpdateModel(reference, "");
```

It has a shitload of overloads. This works though

Answer (score 1):

As Gert Arnold says, you're not actually modifying any of the `Reference` values so nothing will be updated.  By calling `db.Entry(reference).State = EntityState.Modified` you're just setting the retrieved entity's state to modified in the `ChangeTracker`.  When you call `SaveChanges`() it's just going to update the Reference record in the database with the same values that you fetched.

You need to update some of the Reference instance properties to see a change.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            Reference reference = db.References.Single(x => x.Id == id);
            reference.HeaderText = "Changed";
            /* No need to interact with the change tracker as the entity is already tracked and you've made a change */
            // db.Entry(reference).State = EntityState.Modified;


            /* Create/Modify/Update/Delete other entities */

            db.SaveChanges();
            //Other stuff regarding files/images

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
     }
```

Comment: Weird. Microsofts own guides and the scaffolding templates just uses db.Entry(reference).State = EntityState.Modified; and SaveChanges();
So what you're saying is that I have to go through all the properties in the model and update them one by one? I thought the EF model binder handled that automatic? I need an Update() function :) Like in regular LINQ

Comment: The model binder binds the data from the submitted page to your action method's parameters (and your therefor your Models); it does nothing with EF.

Comment: Yep, thats what i meant :)

Comment: I'm still confused.  Nothing in your action method suggests what you're trying to update?   If you're updating a Reference record then your action method would be Edit(Reference reference).  Then in your body you would Attach the reference value to the context and set it's state to modified.

Comment: AFAIK the scaffolding template passes references, not id values. So the object is sent to the client, modified, sent back to the service layer and then its state is set to `Modified`. That's quite different from re-fetching the object by id.